# Do C major and B-flat major have a deep connection?

Tags: theory, scales, modulation

I decided to research where I can "easily" modulate from C major using dominant seventh chord (modulating to a major key we are). In this case I define the word "easily" in the following way - **There should be at least one CONSONANT chord in C major in which at least TWO of its tones are contained in the modulating dominant seventh**. Motivation of this definition is that I want a dominant seventh to be well-connected and supported by a consonant chord.

If we choose only those modulating chords then it seems like the "destination" keys are those contained in the scale of B-flat major.

I find it very interesting that the keys that I can modulate to in a way defined earlier, ALL of them are contained in a different major scale.

**Question**: Is it a 1) coincidence (overfit) 2) a bug in my calculation 3) a worthy observation worth a further meditation?

**Further observation**: If instead of resolving to a new tonic we do a deceptive resolution to the 6th scale degree (relative key), then the possible destination keys are those contained in G major scale.

**P.S.** I understand the question might be formulated in a confusing way, so am open to edits.

Comment: Is _what_ a coincidence?

Comment: Will edit it now

Comment: For example what would be a key to which it is not possible to easily modulate from C major? What are keys contained in the scale of Bb major, do you mean major and minor keys? Bb minor also one of those keys or not? What is the question really - what is the statement, the validity of which is questionable?

Comment: If I understood your comment to Tim's answer, C -> Ab7 -> Db would not count as an "easy" modulation, because Ab7 doesn't have two tones in common with any "consonant" triad in the C major scale? But IMO, C -> Ab7 -> Db is kind of like the mother of all easy modulations, the sort of thing that is taught as the first example of what a modulation means. :)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica ok, probably this was a bad and confusing term "easy". These are the modulations with two common tones, and I wanted to focus on them.

Comment: I think it's possible to find an elegant-sounding trick to modulate to any key you want. If you want to see the possibility for this one specific type of modulation as evidence of some kind of a deep connection, then that's OK and it might be useful. I think it's important to explore the world of music first-hand and associate things with meanings that are tied to your personal history and feelings. No-one sees things from the same perspective as you. Music theory tries to be a general-purpose tool, but its language isn't very emotional, unless you somehow experience the things personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer based on this comment from OP to Tim's attempt at an answer:

> look. In order to use B7 I want to place a chord before it which is
>   either a minor or a major triad from c major scale, that will contain
>   at least two tones in common with B7. And there is no such

Okay, so the criteria seem to be two common tones on a major or minor **triad** from the C major scale, held in common the with dominant seventh of the new key.  Is that correct?

If so, Tim has a large part of it, which I'll repeat here:

> C and E are in C7.
>
> D and F are in G7 (the dominant of C).
>
> E and G are in C7.
>
> F and A are in F7.
>
> G and B are in G7 (dom of C again).
>
> A and C are in D7.
>
> B and D are in G7 (dom. again)

To Tim's list, I'd also add:

D and F are also in B-flat7.

E and G are also in A7.

A and C are also in F7.

B and D are also in E7.

We also need to consider:

C and G are in C7.

D and A are in D7.

E and B are in E7.

F and C are in F7.

G and D are in G7.

A and E are in A7.

B and F can't make a major/minor triad.

Overall, these allow modulations to F, G, A, B-flat, D, and E-flat.  It's true that all of these destination tonic notes are contained in the B-flat major scale.  (They are also contained in the G minor scale.)

As to whether this is a "coincidence," I'm not sure what the definition is for a "coincidence."  These destination tonic notes all occur in particular scales because of the rules you set up.  A dominant seventh chord is composed of three stacked thirds: a major third, and two minor thirds.  As seen above, any of these thirds can be held as common tones from a major or minor triad, but the fact that there are two minor thirds allows for some ambiguity in possible destination keys.  Since major and minor triads also contain a perfect fifth, and the dominant seventh contains a perfect fifth, that interval can also be a potential source of the two common tones.

It's not surprising that B-flat would emerge as a possible destination, as the production of the dominant seventh *added* to a pre-existing triad in a key means you get to stack a minor third on top of many intervals in the scale to form a dominant seventh.  Thus, you can stack a minor third on top of C-E-G to get a C7.  The addition of B-flat to the C major scale thus is simply created by the constraint that says you must start with triads and then allow dominant seventh chords.  You can thus create a dominant seventh on any note of the C major scale using those criteria, except for B.  But note why you exclude B: B7 is a perfectly fine secondary dominant (V/iii) and would lead to a destination key of E, which would not be in your B-flat major scale.  However, the arbitrary constraint of holding *two* common tones between a triad disallows this potential modulatory chord.  If instead the constraint was "build a dominant seventh on any note of the scale," then one might equivalently argue that F major is the scale with the "deep connection" to C major.

It's the rules you set up in your system that determine the outcome.

Similarly, E-flat occurs as a destination key due to the minor third ambiguity I mentioned above.  You can use the D-F third in C major as both a 5th-7th in G7 or as a 3rd-5th in B-flat7.  Note again that this particular case is special: the B-flat7 introduces *two* chromatic tones into the modulatory dominant seventh.  No other chord does this.  Well, B7 would have done it too, but you excluded that for arbitrary reasons above, so we're just left with B-flat7, which creates the pathway to E-flat.  If you instead used criteria that said, "Keep two common tones, but also only allow one new chromatic pitch to be included in the dominant seventh," then both B-flat7 and B7 would be excluded, thereby excluding both E-flat and E as destination keys (and again allowing F major to have the "deep connection").

It all depends on the rules you set up.  By varying them, you could easily allow modulation to many more keys or, alternatively, constrain possible modulations to only a few keys.

Answer (score 1):

> Do C major and B-flat major have a deep connection?

`B` flat major is the subdominant of `C` major's subdominant. That doesn't seem to be *deep*.

> Question: Is it a 1) coincidence (overfit) 2) a bug in my calculation 3) a worthy observation worth a further meditation?

Given only those three choices I would say "coincidence." But really, it's just the outcome of the rule you created.

Requiring two common tones with the dominant seventh chord seems to categorically rule out using the subdominant of the new key. So we can't use these...

[image]

...where all the pivot chords are common to both keys.

Why categorically rule out those modulations to the modal regions? Other than to avoid the one to `E` minor with the `E` natural in the pivot that doesn't fit into `B` flat major.

The only thing that makes `B` flat major emerge is a *arbitrary* rule, not a real harmonic connection.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take it bit by bit. Diatonic notes from key C - C D E F G A B.

C and D are in **D7**.

D and E are in **E7**.

F and G are in **G7** (the dominant *of* C).

G and A are in **A7**.

A and B are in **B7**.

So already we can, using your criteria, modulate into **G/Gm; A/Am; D/Dm; E/Em**.

C and E are in **C7**.

D and F are in **G7** (the dominant *of* C).

E and G are in **C7**.

F and A are in **F7**.

G and B are in **G7** (dom *of* C again).

A and C are in **D7**.

B and D are in **G7** (dom. again).

So keys **F, B♭ and G** are available.

That's a quick look at it!

Comment: I do not think we can modulate to E. The dominant seventh "leading" to E is (B, D sharp, F sharp, A). And there is no **consonant** chord containing A and B in C major. Am I right?

Comment: There is a chord containing A and B (B7), both of which are in key C. I thought that's what you wanted - any chord containing two diatonic notes from C. What's your definition of a 'consonant chord'?

Comment: My bad. It was confusing. By definition from Tchaikovsky a consonant chord is actually a minor or a major triad.

Comment: So I want to have a major or minor triad chord that contains at least two tones from the dominant seventh

Comment: I thought that's what I did. Now, I'm confused.

Comment: look. In order to use B7 I want to place a chord before it which is either a minor or a major triad from c major scale, that will contain at least two tones in common with B7. And there is no such